# Boto3 Amazon S3 (Python package) - getting only files that fill a condition (a filtered bucket.list())

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I have a S3 server with millions of files under each bucket. I want to download files from a bucket, but to download only files that meet a particular condition.
Is there a better way than getting all bucket and then checking the particular condition while iterating over the files?
As can be seen here:

```
import os
# Import the SDK
import boto
from boto.s3.connection import OrdinaryCallingFormat

LOCAL_PATH = 'W:/RD/Fancy/s3_opportunities/'

bucket_name = '/recording'#/sampledResponseLogger'

# connect to the bucket
print 'Connecting...'
conn = boto.connect_s3(calling_format=OrdinaryCallingFormat()) #conn = boto.connect_s3()

print 'Getting bucket...'
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)

print 'Going through the list of files...' 
bucket_list = bucket.list()

for l in bucket_list:

    keyString = str(l.key)

    # SOME CONDITION
    if('2015-08' in keyString):

        # check if file exists locally, if not: download it
        filename=LOCAL_PATH+keyString[56:]
        if not os.path.exists(filename):

            print 'Downloading file: ' + keyString + '...'

            # Download the object that the key represents
            l.get_contents_to_filename(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only mechanism available for filtering `ListBucket` operations on the server side is the `prefix`.  So, if your objects in S3 have some sort of an implied directory structure (e.g. `foo/bar/fie/baz/object1`) then you can use the prefix to list only the objects that start with, for example, `foo/bar/fie`.  If your object names do not display this hierarchical naming, there really isn't anything you can do except list all of the objects and filter using your own mechanism.